# Avoid exposing too many assemblies to client consuming WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, assemblies, business-logic

I need a bit of guidance here. I have a WCF service that is part of a larger solution. Currently, too many assemblies must be referenced by an end-consumer due to inheritance issues. For example, here is my basic project setup:

**MyProject.Domain**

```
namespace MyProject.Domain
{
    public interface IFooable{}

    public class Foo : IFooable{}
}
```

**MyProject.Contracts**

```
namespace MyProject.Contracts
{
    [DataContract]
    public class FooData : IFooable{}

    [ServiceContract]
    public class IFooService
    {
        IEnumerable<FooData> GetFoos();
    }
}
```

**MyProject.Proxies**

```
namespace MyProject.Proxies
{
    public class WCFClient{}
}
```

The problem lies here:

```
class ConsumerCode
{
    private WCFClient = new WCFClient();

    void consumeService()
    {
        // Compiler error. No reference to MyProject.Domain.IFooable
        var foos = WCFClient.GetFoos();
    }
```

That means an end-consumer who uses the **FooData** object will have to also include a reference to **MyProject.Domain**, which stinks because I shouldn't have to expose the Business Logic Layer to the end-client of a WCF service.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Is there a benefit of implementing Domain.IFooable by Contracts.FooData? If you remove this dependency then your domain namespace objects are not exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty straightforward- define IFooable in Contracts, not in Domain.

The logic here is that anything that is exposed to the client is (by definition) a contract or part of a contract, not a domain entity.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you here. However, what if IFooable doesn't make sense within the Contracts assembly? For instance, my particular situation has Domain objects and Contract objects inheriting from an INotifiable interface, that has nothing to do with the Contracts exposed via the service.

Comment: I guess you're right. The INotifiable interface IS a service (albeit not a WCF service). I think I just needed to ponder the semantic definitions of my separate assemblies before I was totally convinced.

Comment: If INotifiable has nothing to do with a contract, then you should be able to remove INotifiable from its inheritance chain.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is for any X, if changing X would require recompiling the client, then X is part of the contract. The contract is the agreement between the client and the service about what data structures will be used for communication.